# Log4j write nothing

Tags: java, spring-mvc, log4j

I have a problem with log4j, write nothing in the console and don't generate the log file. I have no error, no exception and no messages on my eclipse console, it's only do nothing.

log4j.properties (in src/main/resources)

```
    # Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:/log4j-application.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

And my Sample Controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    ParametroImpl param;

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public ModelAndView test(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
        logger.info("PACOPEPE");
        return new ModelAndView("home");

    }
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: As you have controller, where are you deploying this webapp? server in eclipse or standalone server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, stdout, file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put your log4j.properties in src

Or change your Logger

```
final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HomeController.class);
```

to

```
final static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(HomeController.class.getName());
```